# metasearch undefined search method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I am working on a rails 3 app, I am trying to use the `meta_search` gem.

After adding the gem to the `GemFile` and running `bundle install`, it seems that there is no `search` method.

```
undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x00000104134458>
```

I am using something similar to the examples:

```
@search = Bill.search(params[:search])
@bills = @search.all
```

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: When you ran `bundle install` did you see `meta_search` in the output?

Comment: Yes. in the out put it can be read `Using meta_search (1.0.5)`. Could it be a incompatibility of versions I am using rails 3.0.7.

Comment: I've solved it, I installed `squell` and restarted the server. It might have been that I did not restart the server.

Comment: Cool, yeah - gotta restart the server :)  Well done.  Put your own solution in an answer below so the question shows an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that the problem was between the chair and the keyboard.

I have forgotten to restart the server. After doing so it worked flawlessly.